# Rematch redux passing payloads

Tags: reactjs, redux

Could some one tell me how to pass payloads dynamically in the below code.

```
//On click code

<Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.props.inc}>
```

```
//dispatching action 

const mapDispatchToProps =  ({ models: { increment}, mod : {decrement}})  => ({
  inc: () => increment(1),
  dec: () => decrement(1),
});
```

I want the payload 1 to be passed dynamically.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not call the func immediately, only pass

```
const mapDispatchToProps =  ({ models: { increment}, mod : {decrement}})  => ({
  inc: (value)=>increment(value),
  dec: (value)=>decrement(value),
});
```

than you can anything:

```
// in component
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={()=>this.props.inc(3)}>
```

Comment: ive tried it but app doesnt respond.any other ideas?